# Enviar formulario con PHP

Tags: php, html

Qusiera saber en este código, a que email será enviado el mensaje cada vez que alguien envíe un formulario. Quisiera poner que el mail al que va a ser enviado el formulario, sea uno que especifique yo, cómo puedo hacer eso? Les comparto mi código. El código de PHP es:

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['asunto']) && !empty($_POST['msg']) && !

empty($_POST['email'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$asunto $_POST['asunto']; 
$msg $_POST['msg'];
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$header="From: noreply@example.com". "\r\n";
$header.= "Reply-To: noreply@example.com". "\r\n"; 
$header. "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
$to= mail($email, $asunto, $msg, $header);

if ($mail) { echo "<h4>¡Mail enviado exitosamente!</h4>";

}

}
```

Comment: Pues veo que tu función `mail` está mal escrita, no es ail, además querecibe el subject como segundo parámetro. Acá lo puedes ver https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: @gaidyjg Estaría bien ahí? O tendría que reemplazar el $to por $mail? Donde dice mail iría el mail a que es enviado, no es cierto?

Comment: El mensaje se enviaría a la dirección que haya en la variable **`$email`**, que recogiste del POST aquí: `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: Muchas Gracias @A.Cedano

Comment: Parece que tienes una confusión de variables. Si llamas `$to` al resultado de la llamada a la función `mail()`, entonces, en la verificación del `if` debes usar `$to`, en cambio, si la llamas `$mail`, en el `if` debes usar `$mail`. Las variables se pueden llamar como quieras, pero usa los nombres que les hayas dado, procurando, por claridad del código, que al leerlas ya sepas de qué se trata.

Comment: Cuidado, hay un typo aqui: `$msg $_POST['msg'];` falta el `=`. Adicional la variable `$mail` no está definida y dará error en el último if.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien indica el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) el correo sería enviando a la dirección que pongas en el primer parámetro de la función `mail()`, que en tu caso sería `$email`.

Lo que pareces tener es una confusión de variables. Es simple: puedes llamar tus variables como quieras, a condición de que luego uses lo que has definido, no otra cosa. También, por claridad de código, se recomienda que tus variables hagan referencia a lo significa, de modo que al verlas tú o cualquier otro programador (pensemos en un proyecto grande donde participen varias personas) se sepa a qué uso están destinadas esas variables.

Otra práctica que yo recomiendo es asignar los datos de las superglobales mediante el [operador de fusión de null (??)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php) si tienes PHP 7+, o mediante [operadores ternarios](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) si tienes PHP anterior a la versión 7 y luego usar las variables asignadas en el resto del código, olvidando en lo adelante las superglobales. Así el código queda más claro, más limpio y menos propenso a errores.

Aplicando lo dicho, tu código quedaría así:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    /*
       Asumiendo que tienes PHP 7+ 
       usaremos el operador de fusión de null (??)
       Si no es el caso debes hacer las asignaciones con este estilo:
       $name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : NULL;
    */
    
    $name = $_POST['name'] ?? NULL;
    $asunto= $_POST['asunto'] ?? NULL; 
    $msg = $_POST['msg'] ?? NULL;
    $email = $_POST['email'] ?? NULL;
    if ($name && $asunto && $msg && $email) { 
        $header="From: noreply@example.com". "\r\n";
        $header.= "Reply-To: noreply@example.com". "\r\n"; 
        $header. "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();
        /*
           $status sería un nombre más descriptivo
           y que da lugar a menos confusión
        */
        $status= mail($email, $asunto, $msg, $header);
    
        if ($status) { 
            echo "<h4>¡Mail enviado exitosamente!</h4>";
        }
}
```

**POST-DATA**:

Aquí no queda claro para qué recoges `$name`. Si no lo vas a usar, no lo recojas ni lo verifiques en el `if`.